# Disable Selenium & Chrome Driver Logging

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The Chrome Driver prints `Starting ChromeDriver x on port y...`, `Only local connections are allowed.` and so on when starting, and Selenium prints `ChromeDriver was started successfully.` and also notifies me when it can't find an exact match for my CDP version.

How can I disable these messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it will disable all and any logging for chrome driver

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.Builder;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService;

public class DisableLogging {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium.remote").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        DriverService.Builder<ChromeDriverService, Builder> serviceBuilder = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().withSilent(
            true);
        ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = serviceBuilder.build();
        chromeDriverService.sendOutputTo(new FileOutputStream("target/chromedriver_log.txt", true));
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService);
        driver.quit();
    }
```